# tikz grid of plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I have many (>20) tikz environment and I need to plot them in a grid of plots. Here is a simple example; consider the following 4 plots. How to plot them in a 2 by 2 grid?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds,calc}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=1cm,font = \tiny,auto]%,on grid
    \tikzstyle{state}=[shape=circle,thick,draw,minimum width=+2ex,minimum height=+3ex,inner sep=+.2pt]

    \node[state] (a31) {$a_{31}$};
    \node[state,above of=a31] (a21) {$a_{21}$};
    \node[state,  very thick, above of=a21] (a11) {$a_{11}$};

    \node[state,right of=a11] (a12) {$a_{12}$};
    \node[state,below of=a12] (a22) {$a_{22}$};
    \node[state,below of=a22] (a32) {$a_{32}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}


    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=1cm,font = \tiny,auto]%,on grid
        \tikzstyle{state}=[shape=circle,thick,draw,minimum width=+2ex,minimum height=+3ex,inner sep=+.2pt]
        \node[state] (a31) {$a_{31}$};
        \node[state,above of=a31] (a21) {$a_{21}$};
        \node[state, very thick, above of=a21] (a11) {$a_{11}$};

        \node[state,right of=a11] (a12) {$a_{12}$};
        \node[state,below of=a12] (a22) {$a_{22}$};
        \node[state,below of=a22] (a32) {$a_{32}$};

        \path[->,draw,thick]
        (a11) edge node {}(a12)
        (a11) edge node {}(a21);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=1cm,font = \tiny,auto]%,on grid
        \tikzstyle{state}=[shape=circle,thick,draw,minimum width=+2ex,minimum height=+3ex,inner sep=+.2pt]

        \node[state] (a31) {$a_{31}$};
        \node[state,above of=a31] (a21) {$a_{21}$};
        \node[state, very thick, above of=a21] (a11) {$a_{11}$};

        \node[state,right of=a11] (a12) {$a_{12}$};
        \node[state,below of=a12] (a22) {$a_{22}$};
        \node[state,below of=a22] (a32) {$a_{32}$};

        \path[->,draw,thick]
        (a12) edge node {}(a22)
        (a21) edge node {}(a31);
    \end{tikzpicture}

     \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=1cm,font = \tiny,auto]%,on grid
        \tikzstyle{state}=[shape=circle,thick,draw,minimum width=+2ex,minimum height=+3ex,inner sep=+.2pt]

        \node[state] (a31) {$a_{31}$};
        \node[state,above of=a31] (a21) {$a_{21}$};
        \node[state, very thick, above of=a21] (a11) {$a_{11}$};

        \node[state,right of=a11] (a12) {$a_{12}$};
        \node[state,below of=a12] (a22) {$a_{22}$};
        \node[state,below of=a22] (a32) {$a_{32}$};

        \path[->,draw,thick]
        (a12) edge node {}(a22)
        (a31) edge node {}(a32);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do the individual tikzpictures get captions?

Comment: @ leandriis yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer uses a matrix in two different way. Either a matrix of `pic`s or using matrices to draw the sub diagrams. Unfortunately, one cannot nest matrices ... yet.

**Matrix of pics**: You can define a pic for the repeating things, and some simple macro to add the arrows. That way you do not have to repeat so many things. The `pic` can be defined in such a way that you only need to specify the arrows, e.g.

```
\pic{scheme={11->12,11->21}};
```

yields

[image]

The full picture is obtained with

```
    \matrix[column sep=1cm,row sep=1cm]{ 
        \pic{scheme}; & \pic{scheme={11->12,11->21}};\\
        \pic{scheme={12->22,21->31}}; & \pic{scheme={12->22,31->32}};\\
        };
```

[image]

The distance between the circle nodes is controlled by `node distance`, and the distance between the blocks by `row sep` and `column sep`, respectively.

This is the full code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=1em,font = \tiny,auto,
    state/.style={shape=circle,draw,minimum width=+2ex,minimum
    height=+3ex,inner sep=+.2pt},arr/.style={->,thick,draw},
    pics/scheme/.style={code={%
    \path foreach \X [count=\mycolumn] in {-0.5,0.5}
    {foreach \Y [count=\myrow] in {1,0,-1}
    {(\X,\Y) node[state,
        line width={0.6pt+ifthenelse(\myrow+10*\mycolumn==11,1,0)*0.4pt}
        ] 
        (-\myrow-\mycolumn) 
    {$a_{\myrow\mycolumn}$} 
    }};
    \def\ArrDraw##1##2->##3##4;{
    \draw[arr] (-##1-##2) -- (-##3-##4);}
    \edef\tempnone{none}%
    \edef\temparg{#1}%
    \unless\ifx\temparg\tempnone
    \foreach \X in {#1}
    {\expandafter\ArrDraw\X;}
    \fi 
    }},pics/scheme/.default=none]
    \matrix[column sep=1cm,row sep=1cm]{ 
        \pic{scheme}; & \pic{scheme={11->12,11->21}};\\
        \pic{scheme={12->22,21->31}}; & \pic{scheme={12->22,31->32}};\\
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Using matrices for the sub diagrams**: Each of these diagrams is a simple `matrix of nodes`, which can be automatically filled. `positioning` allows you to position these matrices relative to each other.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=1cm,font = \tiny,auto,
    state/.style={shape=circle,thick,draw,minimum width=+2ex,minimum
    height=+3ex,inner sep=+.2pt},arr/.style={->,very thick,draw},
    mymat/.style={matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells,column sep=1em,
    row sep=1em,cells={nodes={state,execute at begin node={%
    $a_{\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn}$}}}}]%,on grid
   \matrix[mymat]  (mat11) { |[very thick]| & \\ 
        & \\
        & \\};
   \matrix[mymat,right=of mat11] (mat12)  { |[very thick]| & \\ 
        & \\
        & \\};
   \draw[arr] (mat12-1-1) --    (mat12-1-2);
   \draw[arr] (mat12-1-1) --    (mat12-2-1);
   \matrix[mymat,below=of mat11] (mat21)  { |[very thick]| & \\ 
        & \\
        & \\};
   \draw[arr] (mat21-1-2) --    (mat21-2-2);
   \draw[arr] (mat21-2-1) --    (mat21-3-1);
   \matrix[mymat,right=of mat21] (mat22)  { |[very thick]| & \\ 
        & \\
        & \\};
   \draw[arr] (mat22-1-2) --    (mat22-2-2);
   \draw[arr] (mat22-3-1) --    (mat22-3-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: It is very easy to integrate captions into this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\tikzset{
    state/.style={shape=circle,draw,minimum width=+2ex,minimum
    height=+3ex,inner sep=+.2pt},arr/.style={->,thick,draw},
    pics/scheme/.style={code={%
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=-bb]
    \path foreach \X [count=\mycolumn] in {-0.5,0.5}
      {foreach \Y [count=\myrow] in {1,0,-1}
      {(\X,\Y) node[state,
          line width={0.6pt+ifthenelse(\myrow+10*\mycolumn==11,1,0)*0.4pt}
          ] 
          (-\myrow-\mycolumn) 
      {$a_{\myrow\mycolumn}$} 
      }};
    \end{scope}
    \tikzset{ie86/.cd,#1}
    }},ie86/.cd,arrows/.code={\def\ArrDraw##1##2->##3##4;{
    \draw[arr] (-##1-##2) -- (-##3-##4);}
    \edef\tempnone{none}%
    \edef\temparg{#1}%
    \unless\ifx\temparg\tempnone
    \foreach \XX in {#1}
    {\expandafter\ArrDraw\XX;}
    \fi},arrows/.default=none,
    caption/.code={\path let \p1=($(-bb.east)-(-bb.west)$) in
     (-bb.south) node[below,text width=\x1,align=center,font=\normalsize] 
     {\begin{subfigure}{\x1}
     \caption{#1}
     \end{subfigure}};}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=1em,font = \tiny]
    \matrix[column sep=6mm,row sep=6mm]{ 
        \pic{scheme={caption={abc}}}; & 
        \pic{scheme={arrows={11->12,11->21},caption={}}};\\
        \pic{scheme={arrows={12->22,21->31},caption={blub}}}; &
        \pic{scheme={arrows={12->22,31->32},caption={bla}}};\\
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Several graphs.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Interesting ways. Can individual tikzpictures get captions in these ways?

Comment: @ie86 Absolutely. Are these captions or sub captions? And for which of the two options?

Comment: @ Schrödinger's cat, With caption and subcaptions, similar to the plots that Zarko generated above.

Comment: @ie86 I was offline, sorry. Please see the addendum.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry to ask another question, with your code, is it possible to add color for only some of the nodes? For example in the first plot, color a_11 blue, second plot color a_11 gray and a_21 blue,..?

Comment: @ie86 Sure, that's easy but depends on which of the codes you are looking at. In the code with `mymat` it is as simple as `  \matrix[mymat]  (mat11) { |[very thick,blue]| & |[red]|\\ 
        & \\
        & \\};`. In the other code it is also easy, but the question is what usage one wants to employ for that.

Answer (score 7):

With no captions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, backgrounds,calc,shapes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\tikzset{shorten >=1pt,
        node distance=1cm,
        font = \tiny,
        auto,%on grid
        state/.style = {shape=circle,thick,draw,minimum width=+2ex,minimum height=+3ex,inner sep=+.2pt}
        }
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[state] (a31) {$a_{31}$};
    \node[state,above of=a31] (a21) {$a_{21}$};
    \node[state,  very thick, above of=a21] (a11) {$a_{11}$};

    \node[state,right of=a11] (a12) {$a_{12}$};
    \node[state,below of=a12] (a22) {$a_{22}$};
    \node[state,below of=a22] (a32) {$a_{32}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\hfil
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[state] (a31) {$a_{31}$};
    \node[state,above of=a31] (a21) {$a_{21}$};
    \node[state, very thick, above of=a21] (a11) {$a_{11}$};

    \node[state,right of=a11] (a12) {$a_{12}$};
    \node[state,below of=a12] (a22) {$a_{22}$};
    \node[state,below of=a22] (a32) {$a_{32}$};

    \path[->,draw,thick]
    (a11) edge node {}(a12)
    (a11) edge node {}(a21);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{11mm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[state] (a31) {$a_{31}$};
    \node[state,above of=a31] (a21) {$a_{21}$};
    \node[state, very thick, above of=a21] (a11) {$a_{11}$};

    \node[state,right of=a11] (a12) {$a_{12}$};
    \node[state,below of=a12] (a22) {$a_{22}$};
    \node[state,below of=a22] (a32) {$a_{32}$};

    \path[->,draw,thick]
    (a12) edge node {}(a22)
    (a21) edge node {}(a31);
\end{tikzpicture}
\hfil
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[state] (a31) {$a_{31}$};
    \node[state,above of=a31] (a21) {$a_{21}$};
    \node[state, very thick, above of=a21] (a11) {$a_{11}$};

    \node[state,right of=a11] (a12) {$a_{12}$};
    \node[state,below of=a12] (a22) {$a_{22}$};
    \node[state,below of=a22] (a32) {$a_{32}$};

    \path[->,draw,thick]
    (a12) edge node {}(a22)
    (a31) edge node {}(a32);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With caption and subcaptions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, backgrounds,calc,shapes}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\tikzset{shorten >=1pt,
        node distance=1cm,
        font = \tiny,
        auto,%on grid
        state/.style = {shape=circle,thick,draw,minimum width=+2ex,minimum height=+3ex,inner sep=+.2pt}
        }
\subfloat[]{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[state] (a31) {$a_{31}$};
    \node[state,above of=a31] (a21) {$a_{21}$};
    \node[state,  very thick, above of=a21] (a11) {$a_{11}$};

    \node[state,right of=a11] (a12) {$a_{12}$};
    \node[state,below of=a12] (a22) {$a_{22}$};
    \node[state,below of=a22] (a32) {$a_{32}$};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\hfil
\subfloat[]{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[state] (a31) {$a_{31}$};
    \node[state,above of=a31] (a21) {$a_{21}$};
    \node[state, very thick, above of=a21] (a11) {$a_{11}$};

    \node[state,right of=a11] (a12) {$a_{12}$};
    \node[state,below of=a12] (a22) {$a_{22}$};
    \node[state,below of=a22] (a32) {$a_{32}$};

    \path[->,draw,thick]
    (a11) edge node {}(a12)
    (a11) edge node {}(a21);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\vspace{11mm}
\subfloat[]{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[state] (a31) {$a_{31}$};
    \node[state,above of=a31] (a21) {$a_{21}$};
    \node[state, very thick, above of=a21] (a11) {$a_{11}$};

    \node[state,right of=a11] (a12) {$a_{12}$};
    \node[state,below of=a12] (a22) {$a_{22}$};
    \node[state,below of=a22] (a32) {$a_{32}$};

    \path[->,draw,thick]
    (a12) edge node {}(a22)
    (a21) edge node {}(a31);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\hfil
\subfloat[]{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[state] (a31) {$a_{31}$};
    \node[state,above of=a31] (a21) {$a_{21}$};
    \node[state, very thick, above of=a21] (a11) {$a_{11}$};

    \node[state,right of=a11] (a12) {$a_{12}$};
    \node[state,below of=a12] (a22) {$a_{22}$};
    \node[state,below of=a22] (a32) {$a_{32}$};

    \path[->,draw,thick]
    (a12) edge node {}(a22)
    (a31) edge node {}(a32);
\end{tikzpicture}}
    \caption{my 2 x 2 images}
    \label{fig:fourimages}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Off-topic:**
Code for your images can be significantly shortened if you employ TikZ library `matrix`. For example, the above second example can be written as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\tikzset{M/.style = {matrix of math nodes,
                     ampersand replacement=\&,
                     column sep = 9mm,
                     row sep = 9mm,
                     nodes = {circle, draw, thick, minimum size=+3ex,
                              font=\tiny, anchor=center},
                     },  
every edge/.style =  {draw, ->, thick}
        }
\subfloat[]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m1) [M]
{
    a_{31}  \&  a_{32}  \\
    a_{21}  \&  a_{22}  \\
    a_{21}  \&  a_{22}  \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\hfil
\subfloat[]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m2) [M]
{
    a_{31}  \&  a_{32}  \\
    a_{21}  \&  a_{22}  \\
    a_{21}  \&  a_{22}  \\
};
%
\path   (m2-1-1) edge (m2-1-2)
        (m2-1-1) edge (m2-2-1);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\vspace{11mm}
\subfloat[]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m3) [M]
{
    a_{31}  \&  a_{32}  \\
    a_{21}  \&  a_{22}  \\
    a_{21}  \&  a_{22}  \\
};
%
\path   (m3-1-2) edge (m3-2-2)
        (m3-2-1) edge (m3-3-1);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\hfil
\subfloat[]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m4) [M]
{
    a_{31}  \&  a_{32}  \\
    a_{21}  \&  a_{22}  \\
    a_{21}  \&  a_{22}  \\
};
\path   (m4-1-2) edge (m3-2-2)
        (m3-3-1) edge (m3-3-2);
\end{tikzpicture}}
    \caption{my 2 x 2 images}
    \label{fig:fourimages}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Result is the same as before.

Answer (score 6):

A solution with `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c@{\hspace{1cm}}c}%@{space between columns}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=1cm,font = \tiny,auto]%,on grid
    \tikzstyle{state}=[shape=circle,thick,draw,minimum width=+2ex,minimum height=+3ex,inner sep=+.2pt]

    \node[state] (a31) {$a_{31}$};
    \node[state,above of=a31] (a21) {$a_{21}$};
    \node[state,  very thick, above of=a21] (a11) {$a_{11}$};

    \node[state,right of=a11] (a12) {$a_{12}$};
    \node[state,below of=a12] (a22) {$a_{22}$};
    \node[state,below of=a22] (a32) {$a_{32}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
&
    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=1cm,font = \tiny,auto]%,on grid
        \tikzstyle{state}=[shape=circle,thick,draw,minimum width=+2ex,minimum height=+3ex,inner sep=+.2pt]
        \node[state] (a31) {$a_{31}$};
        \node[state,above of=a31] (a21) {$a_{21}$};
        \node[state, very thick, above of=a21] (a11) {$a_{11}$};

        \node[state,right of=a11] (a12) {$a_{12}$};
        \node[state,below of=a12] (a22) {$a_{22}$};
        \node[state,below of=a22] (a32) {$a_{32}$};

        \path[->,draw,thick]
        (a11) edge node {}(a12)
        (a11) edge node {}(a21);
    \end{tikzpicture}\\[1cm]%space betweem rows 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=1cm,font = \tiny,auto]%,on grid
        \tikzstyle{state}=[shape=circle,thick,draw,minimum width=+2ex,minimum height=+3ex,inner sep=+.2pt]

        \node[state] (a31) {$a_{31}$};
        \node[state,above of=a31] (a21) {$a_{21}$};
        \node[state, very thick, above of=a21] (a11) {$a_{11}$};

        \node[state,right of=a11] (a12) {$a_{12}$};
        \node[state,below of=a12] (a22) {$a_{22}$};
        \node[state,below of=a22] (a32) {$a_{32}$};

        \path[->,draw,thick]
        (a12) edge node {}(a22)
        (a21) edge node {}(a31);
    \end{tikzpicture}
&
     \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=1cm,font = \tiny,auto]%,on grid
        \tikzstyle{state}=[shape=circle,thick,draw,minimum width=+2ex,minimum height=+3ex,inner sep=+.2pt]

        \node[state] (a31) {$a_{31}$};
        \node[state,above of=a31] (a21) {$a_{21}$};
        \node[state, very thick, above of=a21] (a11) {$a_{11}$};

        \node[state,right of=a11] (a12) {$a_{12}$};
        \node[state,below of=a12] (a22) {$a_{22}$};
        \node[state,below of=a22] (a32) {$a_{32}$};

        \path[->,draw,thick]
        (a12) edge node {}(a22)
        (a31) edge node {}(a32);
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: table of tikzpictures]

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the simplest way to achieve this is by putting the individual tikzpictures in subfigures. You can construct these using the subcaption package. Furthermore this offers the possibility to insert captions for each figure.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=1cm,font = \tiny,auto]%,on grid
\tikzstyle{state}=[shape=circle,thick,draw,minimum width=+2ex,minimum height=+3ex,inner sep=+.2pt]

\node[state] (a31) {$a_{31}$};
\node[state,above of=a31] (a21) {$a_{21}$};
\node[state,  very thick, above of=a21] (a11) {$a_{11}$};

\node[state,right of=a11] (a12) {$a_{12}$};
\node[state,below of=a12] (a22) {$a_{22}$};
\node[state,below of=a22] (a32) {$a_{32}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{This is picture 1}
\end{subfigure} \hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=1cm,font = \tiny,auto]%,on grid
    \tikzstyle{state}=[shape=circle,thick,draw,minimum width=+2ex,minimum height=+3ex,inner sep=+.2pt]
    \node[state] (a31) {$a_{31}$};
    \node[state,above of=a31] (a21) {$a_{21}$};
    \node[state, very thick, above of=a21] (a11) {$a_{11}$};

    \node[state,right of=a11] (a12) {$a_{12}$};
    \node[state,below of=a12] (a22) {$a_{22}$};
    \node[state,below of=a22] (a32) {$a_{32}$};

    \path[->,draw,thick]
    (a11) edge node {}(a12)
    (a11) edge node {}(a21);
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{This is picture 2}
\end{subfigure} \\
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=1cm,font = \tiny,auto]%,on grid
    \tikzstyle{state}=[shape=circle,thick,draw,minimum width=+2ex,minimum height=+3ex,inner sep=+.2pt]

    \node[state] (a31) {$a_{31}$};
    \node[state,above of=a31] (a21) {$a_{21}$};
    \node[state, very thick, above of=a21] (a11) {$a_{11}$};

    \node[state,right of=a11] (a12) {$a_{12}$};
    \node[state,below of=a12] (a22) {$a_{22}$};
    \node[state,below of=a22] (a32) {$a_{32}$};

    \path[->,draw,thick]
    (a12) edge node {}(a22)
    (a21) edge node {}(a31);
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{This is picture 3}
\end{subfigure} \hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=1cm,font = \tiny,auto]%,on grid
    \tikzstyle{state}=[shape=circle,thick,draw,minimum width=+2ex,minimum height=+3ex,inner sep=+.2pt]

    \node[state] (a31) {$a_{31}$};
    \node[state,above of=a31] (a21) {$a_{21}$};
    \node[state, very thick, above of=a21] (a11) {$a_{11}$};

    \node[state,right of=a11] (a12) {$a_{12}$};
    \node[state,below of=a12] (a22) {$a_{22}$};
    \node[state,below of=a22] (a32) {$a_{32}$};

    \path[->,draw,thick]
    (a12) edge node {}(a22)
    (a31) edge node {}(a32);
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{This is picture 4}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{This is a grid of figures!}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```